# Create and fill new column using conditions listed in nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

I'm new to python. I have the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB04', 'AB05','AB06'],
'drugNo': ["Osel","Placebo","Not Osel",np.nan,"UKN","Osel"],
'drugName': ['Placebo', 'Vitamin C', np.nan, 'Placebo', '', 'Type X']
})
```

and the dictionary (which can be restructured if needed)

```
cond_dict = {'Anti': {('Osel', 'Not Osel'):'drugNo' }, 
         'Placebo Effect': {'Placebo': 'drugNo', 'Vitamin C': 'drugName'},
         'UNKNOWN': {'drugNo':'UKN'}}
```

I want the end result to include the following data to the dataframe

```
'effect': ['Anti','Placebo Effect','Anti',np.nan,'UNKNOWN','Anti']
```

I can do if it is simple mapping in the dictionary, but the conditions to check involves OR (for any given value) and AND (check multiple column) so I've unable to figure out a way.
The dictionary can be restructured, but I want it to include is the new column is Anti if drugNo is 'Osel' **or** 'Not Osel'. The new column is Placebo Effect if drugNo is Placebo **and** drugName is Vitamin C. The new column is UNKNOWN if the drugNo is UKN. And this information should be in a dictionary, cannot be hardcoded. How can achieve the end result with this?

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Please explain what you have tried, and what is not working for you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: as commented by @Wouter, please add your attempt `in code` and provide the specific issue that you are facing while using your approach. Your current edit to your question only elaborates the problem further.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
df['effect'] = np.where(((df['drugNo']=='Osel')|(df['drugNo']=='Not Osel')),'Anti', 
                           np.where(((df['drugNo']=='Placebo') & (df['drugName']=='Vitamin C')),'Placebo Effect',
                                   np.where(df['drugNo']=='UKN','UNKNOWN',np.nan)))
```

which returns:

```
 ID    drugNo   drugName          effect
0  AB01      Osel    Placebo            Anti
1  AB02   Placebo  Vitamin C  Placebo Effect
2  AB03  Not Osel        NaN            Anti
3  AB04       NaN    Placebo             nan
4  AB05       UKN                    UNKNOWN
5  AB06      Osel     Type X            Anti
```

There were small ambiguities in your descriptions of the conditional logic, but the idea is there.